# Position UILabel to right is NSLayoutConstraint withVisualFormat

Tags: ios, swift3

I am new to NSLayoutConstraint withVisualFormat i want position the label to right corner . But because of the constraint i added it positioned to the left . Please find the code and image sample .One more thing i want label to be 8px of left and right . If it has more text it need expand also .

```
 let views : [String : Any] = ["title" : articleTitleLabel, "body" : articleDescriptionLabel, "image" : articleImageView ,"footer" : articleAuthorLabel]

    let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-5-[image(130)]-5-[title]-5-|",
                                                          options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let widthConstraints1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-5-[image]-5-[body]-5-|",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)

    let heightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-5-[title]-5-[body]-5-[footer]-(>=5)-|",
                                                           options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)

    let heightConstraints1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-5-[image(130)]-(>=5)-|",
                                                            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(widthConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(heightConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(widthConstraints1)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(heightConstraints1)
```

Screenshot of the issue :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To position your `articleAuthorLabel` in the lower-right corner, you'll need to add some horizontal constraints on it.

Try this:

```
let authorConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[footer]-5-|",
                                                       options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                       metrics: nil, views: views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(authorConstraints)
```

To make sure the label does not push past the left side, you could use:

```
"H:|-(>=5)-[footer]-5-|"
```

And make sure that your content hugging priority is high enough to pull the label margins in.

Or, you could do this, and right-align the text:

```
"H:|-5-[footer]-5-|"
```

Comment: Tried it . Not working. My question is to position in right corner . Now it's positioned in left corner

Comment: What did you try? What were the results?

Comment: I tried adding your code. But the label is still positioned to left and not to right